# Можно ли count() использовать в условии where

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста, понимаю что нельзя использовать в where агрегатные функции, но очень интересует вопрос, как можно использовать count в качестве условия в where?

Comment: Подзапросом например...... кстати, почему в where? есть же ещё having

Comment: В условие where мне нужно выводить несколько статусов по звонкам (конечных), но если к примеру прошло 7 звонков, то ставить автоматом недозвон, если 7 звонков не прошло, то не выбирать этот звонок (если он не имеет конечный статус)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+having